# How to reload page after .submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, submit

I want to reload my page after successful login i.e. whether $.post() returns a 1 page should reload and for a 0 it shouldn't.

For example, my initial attempt:

```
var logon = false;

$('#formname').submit(function() {
    $.post('load.php', $('#formname').serialize(), function(data) {
        if(data == '0')
            logon = false;
        else
            logon = true;
    });

    return logon;
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) method:

```
$('#formname').submit(function() {
    $.post('load.php', $('#formname').serialize(), function(data) {
        if(data == '1') {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've intentionally removed the `logon` variable as it is not needed. AJAX is asynchronous so returning this variable from the submit handler is useless because it won't be assigned a value yet.

Comment: hey nice one this is which im looking for...

it works and thank you for this fast answer

Comment: oh damn... now the browser asks after every login whether he should resend POST informations this is bad