# How to reload a page on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal which contains a form. The Modal also contains a Submit and Cancel Button. The cancel button is working fine and it is closing the Modal successfully. Now as per my requirement on Submit Button Click of the Modal the Form is Submitting Successfully by passing the User inputs to Web Service but Modal is not getting closed. Also I need to reload the page on Submit button click event only. Here is my HTML..

```
<div class="modal fade" id="StudentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StudentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <form action="~/GetStudent" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="frmStudent">
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <div class="pull-right">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Close</button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </form>
  </div>
```

I tried following ways to close the Modal ..

```
$('#frmStudent').submit(function() {
$('#StudentModal').modal('hide');
return false;
});
```

As per my Requirement I need to close the Modal on Submit event and reload the page after getting back from Web Service. How can I do this with Jquery?

Note: I am not supposed to use Ajax Call here ..I need to submit form from form action only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload page after .submit()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191559/how-to-reload-page-after-submit)

Comment: @Jordan.J.D That question uses Ajax , i am not using Ajax , on Form Action , i am giving Service URL..How to do in this case..

Comment: hey @Lara, whats the problem using Ajax, the solution in the link posted by Jordan.J.D seems alright.

Comment: My Lead Says not to use Ajax , So can't use here ..Its a kind of Convention for this project..

Comment: Does `/GetStudent` return a 302 redirect response?

Comment: You can't do this from client side without submitting via AJAX. The browser will act according to the web server's response to your POST. So you will have to make the server respond with a redirect.

Comment: Just remove `return false;` in your `submit` event handler.  The natural submit will take you to the action URL.  Just having the `.modal` code in the submit function should be enough. In [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/o1d4pbkn/1), notice how the form fades out before the submit but then proceeds to allow the post action.

Comment: If $('#StudentModal').modal('hide'); is not workink, try woth $('#StudentModal').modal('toggle'); Hope it helps

Answer (score 17):

This HTML will not work:

```
<form onsubmit="window.location.reload();">
```

But this HTML does the job:

```
<form onsubmit="setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},10);">
```

So the browser has enough time to submit the form and then reload the page ;-)

Comment: @Carl Poole: Thank you for the Edit!

Answer (score 5):

after submitting your form you can just make this call via javascript:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to reload when you submit a form, use the `onsubmit` event handler:

```
document.getElementById("frmStudent").onsubmit = function(){
    location.reload(true);
}
```

This code should reload the page, submit your form, and close the modal.